# Подскажите удобную библиотеку и примеры для реализации сверточной сети на Python'е

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Необходимо реализовать сверточную нейронную сеть (СНС) для анализа изображений на Python'е. Естессно, хочется использовать готовую библиотеку, а не писать все от руки.

Проблема в том, что очень туго с наличием понятной документации, туториалов и примеров.

Скачал PyBrain, разобрался, однако там нет готовых сверточных сетей, а с написанными примерами для СНС очень скудно. Видел единственный пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535855/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-pybrain?newreg=30c740cca3c94c4e88bb615974257211). Однако он не до конца понятен, а также прямо скопированный код не работает.
Видел также инфу, что СНС есть в Theano, однако гугл ничего внятного не выдал.

Просьба объяснить, каким образом можно разобраться с возникшей проблемой. Какую библиотеку лучше (проще) всего использовать (в том числе с учетом геморроя при установке), и где можно найти примеры написанных СНС для этой библиотеки.

Comment: Мне кажется искать и изучать надо на английском, на русском вы по-моему много не найдете...  https://www.google.com/search?q=python+CNN+machine+learning+(theano%7Ctensorflow%7Ckeras)&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=python+cnn+~pictures+(theano|tensorflow|keras)+(tutorial|example)&*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О том как работют СНС коротко описанно в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614338/233525) ответе. Если нужно более глубокое объяснение, там я прикрепил ссылку на видео которое идельно обьясняет принцип работы СНС.

На счет библиотеки - если python то однозначно [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). В вашем случае берите высокоуровненвую надстройку [TfLearn](http://tflearn.org/). Там можно пройти быстрый и хорошо задокументированный [туториал](http://tflearn.org/#tflearn-deep-learning-library-featuring-a-higher-level-api-for-tensorflow) для начинающих и посомтреть в сторону сверточных слоев в [документации](http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/).

Если с английским проблем нет то можно посмотреть вот [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APmF6qE3Vjc) видео где пошагово строиться СНС.